# Google Charts hAxis Label Continuous shifted to the left - bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, staging

i have a google charts continuous hAxis that is shifting to the left, in between data points.

so for instance, normally the hAxis label is as follows:

[image: normal labels]

for some reason, without changing anything, when i have this on staging server, it does the following:

[image: weird labels]

this is on a rails app, so it might have to do with assets being combined, but what chart attribute could be causing this?

label1 ends up missing, and everything is shifted to the left.

i know this is not a CSS issue, as when i view source from the SVG, the actual label1 isn't even in the dataset that google charts generates.

i would prefer not to set the hAxis ticks, and avoid switching to Discrete, and am wondering if there is some sort of position being offset.

i tried to play around with allowContainerBoundaryTextCufoff and explicitly setting the minValue and maxValue of hAxis but to no avail.  any ideas why this is being shifted?

Comment: What type of chart is this (eg. ScatterChart, ColumnChart, LineChart, etc)?  Are the labels for measurements or data set names?  Can you show us some code? A sample data set and the chart options would be really helpful.

Comment: we have this in a rails app so things are all over the place (custom js classes), i will try to piece together what i can. whats odd is for the time being, after we specify ticks on the hAxis, the labels are fixed (centered under each data point), but if we dont specify it, only recently does google charts continuous labels to start acting up, and only on staging server.  i still can't figure out what could cause this to change, this is literally the exact same code, this didnt happen before until the last week or two

Comment: I don't really know rails, so I'm not sure how your code is laid out, but if you can just get the javascript to run the `google.visualization.DataTable`'s `.toJson()` function that'd be helpful.  I don't care as much about what the data is as how it is structured.  Also, the chart's options and the type of chart would be helpful.